# How to explode/unwrap all documents using jq?

Tags: json, bigdata, jq

I have a very large file that looks like this:

```
[
  {a: 4, b: [1,2,3]},
  {a: 6, b: [7,8,9]},
]
```

and I would like to transform it to

```
{a: 4, b: 1},
{a: 4, b: 2},
{a: 4, b: 3},
{a: 6, b: 7},
{a: 6, b: 8},
{a: 6, b: 9}
```

using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). The filter `.[] | {a: .a, b: .b[]}` [would work](https://jqplay.org/s/upWg1D6Vowx) for a smaller set of input. Given the size of the file, I want to use `--streaming`. Anyone who could give a pointer on how to use streaming to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the "very large file" fits into your memory, just decompose the array `.[]`, and create your objects as needed using iterations `{a, b: .b[]}`:

```bash
jq -c '.[] | {a, b: .b[]}'
```

```json
{"a":4,"b":1}
{"a":4,"b":2}
{"a":4,"b":3}
{"a":6,"b":7}
{"a":6,"b":8}
{"a":6,"b":9}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bQ_EvDqF9tt)

---

If not, but an array item alone would, use the `--stream` flag to read the file in parts, only consider the items level using `truncate_stream` with level `1`, re-compose the array items using `fromstream`, and create the final objects as above:

```bash
jq --stream -cn 'fromstream(1 | truncate_stream(inputs)) | {a, b: .b[]}'
```

```json
{"a":4,"b":1}
{"a":4,"b":2}
{"a":4,"b":3}
{"a":6,"b":7}
{"a":6,"b":8}
{"a":6,"b":9}
```